# Why is my middle mouse button rotating the camera in the shading tab?

Tags: interface, camera

In every other tab except the Shading tab, middle clicking and dragging rotates the viewport around the point of origin. In the Shading tab, middle clicking and dragging rotates the camera. I am currently using Blender 3.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, checking this setting fixed it in the shading tab.

[image]